# Login as a client no dashboard menu?

Tags: login, dashboard

I want to be able to login to wordpress through a customized function, no dashboard etc showing. I just want the user being logged in and then I want to handle stuff like customized forms, update stuff into db etc for a specific logged in user.

I thought `wp_signon`() looked like a good alternative, but it opens up the dashboard menu that I really didn't want it to. Is there a possible way not show dashboard-menu when logged in (basically show nothing, just being logged in with a cookie) as a client? When I log in as adminstrator (through /wp-admin) I want the "normal" functionality with dashboard etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to the black bar that may run across the top of a web page. That's called the 'Toolbar'. However, an earlier version of it was called the 'Admin Bar', and that name is still used in the code.
To never display it, add this to `functions.php`

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){
        return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

or to just show the bar for admins

```
function my_function_admin_bar($content) {
    return ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ? $content : false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

(Or similarly in a plugin.)

See [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar).

(Also, you should be able to use `wp_signon()` if you wish.)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this myself... if someone stumbles upon the same issue. I installed a plugin called Admin Menu Editor:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

...and in the settings for this plugin I set capability level Administrator for Panel and then the client users I set to another role.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer to help keep the site tidy.  Thanks.